# i am making a app and receiving error:package android.support.v7.p033a.C0517a does not exist

Tags: android

**This is the import statement but I am still getting the error**

```
        import android.support.v7.p033a.C0517a;
        import static android.support.v7.p033a.C0517a.C0516j.AppCompatTheme_alertDialogButtonGroupStyle;
        import static android.support.v7.p033a.C0517a.C0516j.AppCompatTheme_autoCompleteTextViewStyle;
        import static android.support.v7.p033a.C0517a.C0516j.AppCompatTheme_buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle;
        import static android.support.v7.p033a.C0517a.C0516j.AppCompatTheme_buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle;
        import static android.support.v7.p033a.C0517a.C0516j.AppCompatTheme_buttonBarStyle;
        import static android.support.v7.p033a.C0517a.C0516j.AppCompatTheme_buttonStyleSmall;
        import static android.support.v7.p033a.C0517a.C0516j.AppCompatTheme_checkboxStyle;
        import static android.support.v7.p033a.C0517a.C0516j.AppCompatTheme_colorAccent;
        import static android.support.v7.p033a.C0517a.C0516j.AppCompatTheme_colorBackgroundFloating;
        import static android.support.v7.p033a.C0517a.C0516j.AppCompatTheme_colorButtonNormal;
        import static android.support.v7.p033a.C0517a.C0516j.AppCompatTheme_colorControlActivated;
        import static android.support.v7.p033a.C0517a.C0516j.AppCompatTheme_colorControlHighlight;
        import static android.support.v7.p033a.C0517a.C0516j.AppCompatTheme_colorControlNormal;
        import static android.support.v7.p033a.C0517a.C0516j.AppCompatTheme_colorError;
        import static android.support.v7.p033a.C0517a.C0516j.AppCompatTheme_colorPrimary;
        import static android.support.v7.p033a.C0517a.C0516j.AppCompatTheme_colorPrimaryDark;
        import static android.support.v7.p033a.C0517a.C0516j.AppCompatTheme_colorSwitchThumbNormal;
        import static android.support.v7.p033a.C0517a.C0516j.AppCompatTheme_dividerHorizontal;
        import static android.support.v7.p033a.C0517a.C0516j.AppCompatTheme_imageButtonStyle;
        import static android.support.v7.p033a.C0517a.C0516j.AppCompatTheme_switchStyle;
        import static android.support.v7.p033a.C0517a.C0516j.AppCompatTheme_textAppearanceListItemSmall;
```

**This is the use of this package. the following Java file does exist in the support file of the app**

```
case C0517a.C0516j.AppCompatTheme_colorBackgroundFloating /*49*/:
            if (string.equals("1")) {
                z = true;
                break;
            }
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Are you using gradle?

Comment: yes i am using gradle

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using Gradle you should have the following line in your app gradle:

`api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`

or

`api 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-beta01'` with androidX

Android Studio should deal with the import statements once you've rebuilt your project.